# nested methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create a nested method in javaScript like this:

```
Circle= function (){
  this.type1 = function (){
     this.property = {
       color: "red"
     }
  }
  this.type2 = function (){
     this.property = {
       color: "blue"
     }
  }
}
```

Where it could be accessed this way:

```
circle = new Circle();
circle.type2.property.color = "red";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested objects in javascript, best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942398/nested-objects-in-javascript-best-practices)

Comment: `this` is available inside functions and classes, not inside object literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const Circle = function() {
  this.type1 = {
    property: {
      color: "red"
    }
  }
  this.type2 = {
    property: {
      color: "blue"
    }
  }
}

let c = new Circle();

c.type1.property.color = 'violet';

console.log(c.type1.property.color)
```